# Cannot change link color inside div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap3 for a small website, and I need to change the link color in one of my divs.

However, for some reason, the bootstrap link colors are always being applied instead of my custom ones.

CSS:

```
.social a,
.social a:hover,
.social a:focus {
    color: #fefefe;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="social">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
```

I also tried this:

```
.social > a,
.social > a:hover,
.social > a:focus {
    color: #fefefe;
}
```

But doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

**#fefefe** is a white color. Maybe you have white content on a white background.
It should work.

```
body {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.social a,
.social a:hover,
.social a:focus {
    color: #fefefe; // white
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bzvgepxd/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.social a:link` to the list

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I also checked with Google Developer Tools in Chrome, and there it shows that the default bootstrap color scheme is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

either add `!important` to your style:

```
color: #fefefe!important;
```

or better, make sure your styles are loaded AFTER bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mystyle.css">
```

EDIT:

if `<a>` tags is what want to style you might want to apply your color to `:link` and `:visited` too:

```
.social a,
.social a:link,
.social a:visited,
.social a:hover,
.social a:focus {
    color: #fefefe;
}
```

Comment: Custom css is loaded after bootstrap. Adding the !important statement doesn't solve it either.

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe adding styles for `:link` & `:visited` will solve your issue. @JeroenJacobs